# How do I get the data in two columns inside a database table using php

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to get data from the course table which has a primary key -course_id. the table has department and code column. I want to loop through all the courses and print with radio buttons, the department with the department code.

```
   $query = "select *
          from courses";

        $result = $dbc ->query($query);
        
        while ($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {
        print"<input type='radio' name='course' value='$row[course_id]'><br/>";
```

It loops through the courses but doesn't print out anything next to the radio button

Comment: Radio buttons don’t have text. Any text you’ve ever seen next to one is just coincidence. Any “clickable” text next to one is because of an html label tab surrounding them.

Comment: right. but since i'm printing out courses in a loop, how do I assign each radio button  with a different department and dept_code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it should just be something like

```
print "<label><input type='radio' name='course' value='".$row["course_id"]."'>".$row["department"]."</label><br/>";
```

Assuming "department" is the name of your database column then this would print the department name next to each radio button.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. You can use `<label>` to display the text title and value of `radio` for your `dept_code`

Like this

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML">
  <label for="html">HTML</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS">
  <label for="css">CSS</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript">
  <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Note: All radio buttons will have the same name.

#### 2. I don't see your `}` close of the `while`

Comment: the } comes right after the print statement. They all have the same name but i can't figure out how to assign a different value to each button since I'm running it in a loop